# Flask App on local/shared network, who's using my app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am running a flask app on a shared/local network using this like of code in my flask file:

```
app.run(host=[myipaddress], port='5000')
```

Other users (with different IPs) that are connected to the network can access the page by inputting this into their browser:

```
[myipaddress]:5000
```

On my page, I have a submit button. **Is there a way I can see which users are submitting? I've only been able to return information about the computer that I am running (hosting?) the app on.** Here are the lines of code that I've tried to use to get the Windows username:

```
request.headers.get('X-Remote-User')
request.environ.get('REMOTE_USER')
getpass.getuser()
os.environ.get( "USERNAME" )
```

Comment: No, that would be a huge breach of privacy. You can use some form of single-sign-on using Windows or Active Directory credentials to require users to be logged on before they can submit the form.

Comment: you can get IP address of the user making the request, but this is pretty much it.

Comment: @Marat, that might help me somewhere down the line. What's your preferred method? I've tried ```socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())``` (import socket), but it only returned the IP of the flask hosting machine.

Comment: `request.remote_addr` contains the client IP